# Can a manual Refresh in Excel trigger unrelated code?

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping that this series of events in Excel. Anyone know if it's possible?

1) User triggers seeded Refresh command

2) Unrelated macro runs

3) Refresh is executed

4) Different macro runs

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Manual refresh? As in hitting a button? Which button? If refreshing the entireworkbook then some events may fire.  What is a seeded refresh?

Comment: @QHarr Yes the manual refresh button. Really what I'm referring to is the seeded Application.RefreshAll or PivotTable.Refresh function